# Is it possible to add image buttons in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am now developing windows application using c#.net.
now i want to add four image buttons in datagridview cell like following picture.
Is it possible to do it? is there any control to do as the following picture.

[image]

Best Rgds,
DF

Comment: and a simple google search of `DataGridView Image Button` didn't work for you.. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27146/DataGridView-Image-Button-Cell

Comment: Why people give '-' to this post, i really dont understand.

Comment: Thanks MethodMan, but this is not what i want.

Comment: then start googling until you find what you want

Comment: I didn't downvote but the question shows neither research nor coding nor spelling efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a template field as a column in your grid view. Then in the item template you can put asp image buttons. For example:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="gdv_gridviewname" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image Buttons">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgBtnSomething" ImageURL="Path to your image" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I believe he said windows app, but i theory it's the same.  You need a template field in the datagrid with button controls in it.

Comment: Yep windows app, btw windows have dont have template field isn't it?        I am not using WPF somemore.